# <input type=file> does not work Facebook in-app browser

Tags: android, html

Please forgive me for using a translator.

The issue is related to File Input in Facebook in-app browser .

If user click on `input` of type `file`, gallery opens,I select images, and images are not selected

The Input file tag shows `'No File Chosen'`, values is also ""(Empty String).

It occurred only on Facebook,Instagram In-App browser,in Android environment.

Please suggest me who I can fix it ?

Code:

```
<div class="file-uploader">
<input id="fileupload" type="file" accept="image/*" name="DE_CERTIFICATION" >
<input id="file_YN" type="hidden" name="file_YN" value="N">
<label for="fileupload" class="custom-file-upload">
upload
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: So probably the problem is in the JavaScript code or the server side code

Answer (score 0):

may be you have to wrap this code in form tag to upload the file to your server..i have drafted below code may be this might work...plz check..

```
<div class="file-uploader">
<form action="">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="DE_CERTIFICATION" >
    <input id="file_YN" type="hidden" name="file_YN" value="N">
  <input type="submit" name="uploaded_file" value="upload">
</form>
    </div>
```

In your code in have deleted the label tag, as far as upload button is concerned normally label is not required.